# How to extend MediaWiki session time?

Tags: php

I am trying to extend MediaWiki so that it does not expire after 24 minutes.  Here is what i have done.

1. **PHP Setting Changes** 
   For the sake of testing I decreased all the PHP session parameters to 60 seconds.

I changed them to the following:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime : 60 
session.gc_probability : 1
session.gc_divisor : 1
session.cookie_lifetime : 60
```

2. **Test that PHP sessions are working**
   I then verified that the PHP sessions are working by creating a PHP script that create and display a simple session. After 60 seconds indeed the sessions is automatically destroyed.
3. **Now Going Back to MediaWiki**.
   I logged in to MediaWiki and wait 60 or more seconds, but i am still logged in. The MediaWiki Sessions does not expire. That tells me that the session is handled by MediaWiki, how can i can change or extend that value?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you have set for [`$wgCookieExpiration`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCookieExpiration)?

Comment: $wgCookieExpiration: = 0; $wgSessionsInObjectCache = false; in my LocalSettings.php file. $wgCookieExpiration was set to 180*86400 (180 days i presume). I changed it to 0 (According to mediawiki : "Setting to 0 makes all cookies session-only.")

Comment: I believe that a session only cookie means until the browser window is closed. It states the implementation could be broken, have you tried setting this to 60 as well? What do you see when you view the cookie via a plugin such as [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)?

Comment: Changed $wgCookieExpiration to 60. Installed the cookie plugin. Run the plugin and it display 60 seconds added to the current time. I stay idle for about 2 minutes. Then when i try to access the page again, the cookie is updated with a new time that is 60 seconds from the current time.   The question  is why it does not log me out when the cookie expires and i am trying to access it again.

Comment: Do you have a 'remember me' cookie set? That uses a different setting of [`$wgExtendedLoginCookieExpiration`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgExtendedLoginCookieExpiration).

Comment: Guess what!  No matter what configuration changes i made fixed the issue until i decided to upgrade MediaWiki altogether. I was running version 1.26.2. I upgraded it to 1.28.2 and the cookie expiration flag is set to 60 and wgExtendedLoginCookieExpiration is set to NULL.  Now it expires after 60 seconds. Now i just have to increase 60 seconds to a day (86400) then i am golden.  Thank you so much for pointing me to $wgCookieExpiration flag and the EditThisCookie plugin will be useful in the near future. I was about to go crazy over this one.